# jQuery Autocomplete with Name/Value pairs from ASMX via JSON

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete, asmx

I have two textboxes which I am trying to use for autocomplete. The source data for both is coming from an ASP.NET ASMX web service, returned in JSON format. I'm getting back a List where NameValue is defined as:

`public struct NameValue { public string Name; public string Value; }`

How can I parse this data such that the selected dropdown Name's Value can be stored away in a hidden field?

Here is my code thus far when the page loads, and `msg.d` contains the JSON data (I see `msg.d[0].Name` and `msg.d[0].Value`)

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Services/Team.asmx/GetClubTeams',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
          $('#<%= txtFromTeam2.ClientID %>, #<%= txtToTeam2.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
            source:msg.d
          });
        },
        error: function(xhr, msg) {
          alert(msg);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

Answered my own question. The trick is to know that the Name/Value should be of the form:

`public struct TeamData { public string key; public string value; }`

It appears `value` (lowercase) matters to jQuery.

The `$.ajax()` call is as follows...hope this helps someone:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/Services/Team.asmx/GetClubTeams',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       data: "{}",
       success: function(data) {
         $('#txtFromTeam2').autocomplete({
           source: data.d,
           minLength: 3,
           focus: function(event, ui) {
             $('#txtFromTeam2').val(ui.item.value);
             return false;
           },
           select: function(event, ui) {
             $('#txtFromTeam2').val(ui.item.value);
             $('#<%= txtFromTeam2Id.ClientID %>').val(ui.item.key);
             populatePlayers(ui.item.key);
             return false;
           }
         });
         $('#txtToTeam2').autocomplete({
           source: data.d,
           minLength: 3,
           focus: function(event, ui) {
             $('#txtToTeam2').val(ui.item.value);
             return false;
           },
           select: function(event, ui) {
             $('#txtToTeam2').val(ui.item.value);
             $('#<%= txtToTeam2Id.ClientID %>').val(ui.item.key);
             return false;
           }
         });
       },
       error: function(xhr, msg) {
         alert(msg);
       }
     });
```